# How to use json as a structure member in protobuf or grpc?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, grpc

When develop with javascript we always need to transport json with rpc. Now I want to use json as structure member of message in grpc. Please see below:

```
message HelloRequest{
    int32 hello = 1;
    json world = 2
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: You can simply use a string to carry your JSON. "json world=2;" can be remplaced by "string world=2;"

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to do this, depending on if you know the structure of your JSON in advance. If you do you can simply write a separate message for your JSON object and include that in your original message:

```
message SomeJSONMessage {
    // Attributes of your JSON here
}

message HelloRequest {
    int32 hello 1;
    SomeJSONMessage message = 2;
}
```

This is possible because every JSON type [maps natively](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) to a Protobuf type.

If you do not know the structure of your JSON in advance you would have to use a [`google.protobuf.Struct`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#struct), which is basically a JSON without a defined structure:

```
message HelloRequest {
    int32 hello 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct message = 2;
}
```

This maps easily to well-known types in many programming languages (object in JS, dict in Python), but you won't have any guarantee about what attributes it contains.

Comment: Hi Gmolau, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to use this in golang. But I can't transmit json into  google.protobuf.Struct. Do you know if golang support the undefined structure json?

Comment: The [generated Go code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated) does support the struct type, but since I have no experience with Go I can't tell you how to make it work. Protobuf structs do have their idiosyncrasies (in Python you have to call `get_or_create_struct()` on the struct field), so it might be necessary to have a closer look at the [Go documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the support from community, here I'd use ***google.protobuf.Struct*** or ***gogo/protobuf/types/struct.pb.go***

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message HelloRequest{
    int32 hello = 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct world = 2
}
```

I'm currently using *go* **v1.16** and *grpc-gateway* **v1.16**. The ***protoc*** command to gen *<your_file>.pb.go* should add this if you prefer gogo protobuf to google protobuf (the ***xx.pb.go*** files located in *pb* folder) :

```
    --gogo_out=plugins=grpc,\
Mgoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types,\
Mgoogle/protobuf/duration.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types,\
Mgoogle/protobuf/empty.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types,\
Mgoogle/protobuf/struct.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types,\
Mgoogle/api/annotations.proto=github.com/gogo/googleapis/google/api,\
Mgoogle/protobuf/field_mask.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types:\
pb \
```

Last but not least, I can provide an example in which I'm using gogo protobuf. Please take a look at the code below!

```
import (
     "github.com/gogo/protobuf/jsonpb"
     "github.com/gogo/protobuf/types"
)

.....
world := &types.Struct{}
helloRequest := &pb.HelloRequest{World: world}
bts := []byte(`{"status":200,"user":{"id":1,"name":"A","age":26,"phone":null,"skills":{"backend":"Golang","frontend":"React"},"hobbies":["coding","running"]}}`)
    
// Every pb are proto.Message so that we have to use jsonpb package 
// instead of json package
err := jsonpb.Unmarshal(bytes.NewBuffer(bts), world)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The response json should be:

```
{ 
  "hello": 0,
  "world": {
    "status": 200,
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "age": 26,
      "phone": null,
      "skills": {
        "backend": "Golang",
        "frontend": "React"
      },
      "hobbies": [
        "coding",
        "running"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you very specifically want that JSON structure and do not care about how pretty your proto files are, you can use the `google.protobuf.Struct` types to build a custom JSON structure.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto

In this case, you probably want `google.protobuf.ListValue`.